# Can I cache ItemGroup with metadata?

Tags: msbuild

Assume I have a ItemGroup with metadata that takes some times to build (10 seconds):

```
<Target Name="BuildItemGroup">
    <ItemGroup>
        <File Include="5">
            <Value>5a</Value>
        </File>
        <File Include="4">
            <Value>4a</Value>
        </File>
        ...
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Wait 10 seconds..." Importance="High" />
</Target>
```

And I am going to use the same ItemGroup few times in a recursive MSBuild task:

```
<Target Name="Recursive" DependsOnTargets="BuildItemGroup" Condition="$(Value) > 0" >
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=$(Value)" />
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
   <Value>5</Value>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Default" DependsOnTargets="Recursive" />
```

It will takes extra 40 seconds finish the `Recursive` task for 4 loops.  Is there a way to cache the ItemGroup in such manner for loop usage?

Answer (score 1):

No, calling MSBuild task will create new context which will re-evaluate all the properties and items.
The only way you can use to pass data between parent\child contexts is properties (and environment variables which become global properties).

Depending on how big this list is - you can try to pass it as a property (loosing metadata) and re-create itemgroup in your child msbuild context.

Or you can switch to inline tasks using C# and d whatever you want with full C# power - e.g. save data to disk and read it back from the file.

UPDATE: Finally I've done such inline task. Actually it's a pair of tasks one to save and another one - to load persisted items from disk. A bit ugly code - I have to create a serializable copy for Item and metadata classes. But it's good enough as a PoC. It's not guaranteed that it will safely work in multi-threaded environment, especially in your case of 200+ projects.
[See the code in this repository](https://github.com/centur/msbuild.box/blob/master/InlineTask.ItemGroupPersistence.proj)

Comment: Is there a ready to use task that may write ItemGroup + Metadata to file? and read from the file to ItemGroup?

Comment: :) I'm not aware about one. I can try to tie one together for you (as I can see you aren't C# dev, right?) but it's definitely won't happens today and not sure about tomorrow. You can wait or ask this on SO - maybe someone have something ready on hands

Comment: Sorry for taking so long - see my answer update. Usage included in the sample target after tasks definition

Comment: @Alexrey: I manage to solve it using file to store the item group.  All my problems solved and publish to https://github.com/ccy/msbuild.delphi.parallel